# Notepad++: How to remove all string except containing period

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have numerous `SELECT` statements conjoined by `UNION` keyword in a single file. What I want to do is to extract all the `db.table` strings only? How can I delete all words not containing period (.) using regex in notepad++ editor? Database and table are the only ones with a period.

It's okay with me even if new lines are not removed. Though, as a learning bonus for everyone seeing this post, you can also show the regex that trims the new lines, that will show this output:

```
db.table1
db.table2
...
db.tablen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (?<=^|\s)[^.]+(?=$|\s)
Replace: <empty string>
```

### Demo

Note that my replacement only removes the undesired terms in the query; it does not make an effort to remove stray or leftover whitespace.  To do that, you can easily do a quick second replacement to remove whitespace you don't want.

**Edit:**

It appears that Notepad++ doesn't like the variable width lookbehinds I used in the pattern.  Here is a refactored, and more verbose version, which uses strictly fixed width lookbehinds:

```
(^[^.]+$)|(^[^.]+(?=\s))|((?<=\s)[^.]+$)|((?<=\s)[^.]+(?=\s))
```

### Demo

The logic in both of the above patterns is to match a word consisting entirely of non dot characters, which are surrounded on either side by one or more of the following:

- start of the string (`^`)
- end of the string (`$`)
- any type of whitespace (`\s`)

Comment: I don't have NPP in front of me right now, so I can't test there.  Did you turn on regex mode in the find?

Comment: Try this in NPP: [New demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK00Dw/2).  My suspicion is that NPP does not like variable width lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this expression:

```
([\s\S]*?)(\S*(\.)\S*)
```

being replaced with `$2\n` or:

```
(\S*(\.)\S*)|(.+?)
```

with `$1` might work.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/pYpbjf/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lRnIg2/1/)

Comment: It keeps the lines with the dot, but didn't isolate the word itself that contains the dot.